# How to change text in ```<p>``` to number in js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to take the content of the `<p>` tag then change it to a number and multiply it by 2000 then returning it to the `<p>` (this works after I press a select tag that changes the currency from USD to LBP by multiplying the number with 2000)
ps: it's a project for my class
:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="card">
    <img class="imgcar" src="cars/402088-2020-land-rover-range-rover-velar.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:16em">
    <div class="container">
        <h4><b>Range Rover Velar</b><br><b>4 Doors</b><br><b> 5 Passengers</b> </h4>
        <p id="price">100</p><p>$/24hrs</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var p = document.getElementById("price");
var text = p.textContent;
var number = parseInt(text) * 2000;
p.innerHTML = number;
```

Comment: Consider using `document.getElementById` instead of `document.p`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the string to an integer before multiplying with another number:

HTML

```
<div><p id="price">160</p>
```

JS

```
var p = document.getElementById("price");
var text = p.textContent;
var number = parseInt(text) * 2000;
p.innerHTML = number;
```

Comment: try now - instead of - `document.p.innerHTML` you need to use `p.innerHTML` on your last line.. Also in your first line you missed inverted comma on id selector - `var p = document.getElementById(price);` -> `var p = document.getElementById("price");`

Comment: @FirasRihan I hope your problem has been fixed!

Comment: I tried to put an alert before the code just to make sure that it is executing it and it alerted but the code didn't work

Comment: is there a way I can send you the html and js files to see the problem?

Comment: @FirasRihan I have updated the full code. This will definitely works.

Comment: I'm sorry but also didn't work, I'm afraid that I'm writing it wrong

Comment: yes, if this doesn't works then you are doing wrong. You need to post your full page's code in your ques.

Comment: i'll update it just give me a sec, thanks for your help!!

Comment: @FirasRihan The code is ok. NP with this code and should works. Open your browser console and check if there is any other error or warning.

Comment: Firas Rihan Project.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Comment: i replaced it by parseInt the error was replaced by this : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of nul

Comment: @FirasRihan Check if you have used -> `price` id twice or several times. Make sure it's used only one time in your entire page.

Comment: It finally worked!!!! the only problem was that the script must be in the end of the html just to execute the html first. Thanks a lot for your help and your time!!!  Happy holidays

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var text = document.getElementById("price").textContent;

var number = parseInt(text);
number=number*2000;
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = number.toString();
```

Comment: i'll try it now

Comment: Okey.You are missing something that is not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML;

var number = Number(text);

number=number*2000;

document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = number.toString();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I already explained above what the code does,,, Im gonna make a select tag to select the currency so if lbp was chosen the price will be multiplied by 2000

Answer (score 0):

```js
price = document.getElementById("price");
price.innerHTML=eval(price.innerHTML)*2000
```

```html
<div><p id="price">160</p>
```

Comment: Never use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!)

Comment: Eval it calculate the string equation. The price is always decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `parseInt` -  your decimals (assuming this number can have decimals) will be lost. Instead, use `parseFloat`

```js
var num= parseFloat(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML);
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML= num*2000;
```

```html
<p>160.15</p>
```